# Unbind @Ajax.ActionLink after success

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to remove the Unobstrusive microsoft ajax @Ajax.ActionLink bind after click.

something like this:

.cshtml :

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "EditDeliveryZones", new { idConnection = ViewBag.idConnection }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "EditDeliveryZones" }, new { @class = "ajaxdialogopen" })
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.ajaxdialogopen').one('click', function (event) {
     $(this).off('click'); // THIS DOESNT WORK
     this.onclick = null; // THIS DOESN't WORK EITHER
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting something like this in your handler:

```
$(this).removeAttr('data-ajax');
```

I believe `data-ajax` is the attribute that the live handler triggers on, so removing it from the link should prevent it from being treated as an ajax link anymore.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is, what if you need the event? You just do not want it bound n+ times? I am currently having this exact issue. Since its not a jquery event, you really cant un-bind it, but how do you stop it from binding the second time and on?

Comment: @starfighterxyz: I'm not at all clear what you're talking about. Can you create a new question detailing what behavior you're seeing, and provide a link to it from here?

Comment: I appreciate the idea, but I would literally copy and paste the OP. If you remove 'data-ajax' the Ajax.ActionLink, is no longer ajax, and is simply a dormant piece of HTML. That is NOT a solution. "My brakes on my car dont work, so disable them!". The issue here is that event is being bound N+ times. Where N is the number of times you visit the partial page.

Comment: @starfighterxyz: That's not what I gathered from the OP, or I would have answered differently. It sounded to me like he actually did want to remove the AJAX binding during a click event. If your AJAX events are running multiple times, that's because you are running the instantiation javascript multiple times, when it was only intended to be run once per page. There are a number of ways to fix this, the easiest of which is to put the `<script>` reference in your master page instead of the partial view.

Comment: I can see the difference in interpretation, thanks for the response anyway. If only Master Page includes worked in MVC 4. (that is, partial views, where Jquery is used, but not used in a separate javascript file.)

Comment: @starfighterxyz: I don't know what you mean about Master Page includes working "where JQuery is used, but not used in a separate javascript file." I'm sure there's a good solution for your problem, but I don't have enough information about how you're building your pages to address it. If you put together a good description of where your problem is coming from, link to it and I'll see if I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like

```
$('.ajaxdialogopen').click( function( event ) { 
    (event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
});
```

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();` should be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

After reading microsoft and jquery libraries, it uses LIVE, which goes against the selector and not the element. So making the selector not match (aka removing the class) makes the event not trigger anymore.

Valid reason to of why live is deprecated ... hope microsoft update it's libraries soon.

Comment: You talk as if `live` was a bad idea in the first place. It was only deprecated because they decided to integrate it with the `on` and `off` functions. (They deprecated `bind` and `unbind` at the same time, remember?) It's not an inherently bad approach.

Comment: don't take it that personal, i just pointed out that is a VALID reason to deprecate live.

Comment: Sorry if I came across as defensive. I was mostly trying to point out this isn't a valid reason to deprecate `live` at all. The *functionality* of `live` was never deprecated: it just changed syntax. It's still a perfectly legitimate way to do things, and when Microsoft updates its libraries it won't be to change the way these events are bound.

Comment: you can't preventDefault on live because it goes up to the document to fire the handler (which is inefficient compared to .on) also it's not chainable. This makes the use of preventDefault on live events useless, and my friend, from my point of view, that only IS a valid reason to deprecate live in favor to on. bind / unbind is not deprecated, just changed to on and off. bind('click') do a .on('click') now, it works the same.

Comment: By the same logic, `live`/`die` are not deprecated, just changed to on and off. `$(document).on('click', '[data-ajax="true"]', ...)` does the same thing as `$('[data-ajax="true"]').live(...)`. The `on`/`off` API was specifically designed to combine `bind`/`unbind`, `delegate`/`undelegate`, and `live`/`die` into a single function.  And while `preventDefault` doesn't prevent `live` handlers from firing, `stopPropagation` does. Live binding can be more efficient or less efficient than direct binding depending on the situation: so use it wisely, but don't write it off entirely.